# dbWriteTable Load Failure

Tags: r, sqlite, rsqlite

I have been observing strange behavior from `DBI:::dbWriteTable` which seems to be connected to the occurrences of single quotes in input fields of the files I am attempting to read in.

Here is a minimally reproducible example:

```
library(RSQLite)
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = "test_db")

cat("Girls' Shoes\tGirls' Preschool Shoes\nGirls' Shoes\tGirls' Preschool Shoes\nEXPLORER JAKE\tEXPLORER JAKEWITH TOY\n", file = "test.dat")

dbWriteTable(con, name = "test_table", value = "test.dat", head = FALSE, sep = "\t",  field.types = c(V1 = "varchar(25)", V2 = "varchar(25)"))
```

results in:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings, : line 1 did not have 2 elements
```

whereas eliminating one or both single quotes from each line will result in a successful load:

```
cat("Girls' Shoes\tGirls Preschool Shoes\nGirls Shoes\tGirls' Preschool Shoes\nEXPLORER JAKE\tEXPLORER JAKEWITH TOY\n", file = "test.dat")

dbRemoveTable(con, name = "test_table")
dbWriteTable(con, name = "test_table", value = "test.dat", head = FALSE, sep = "\t", field.types = c(V1 = "varchar(25)", V2 = "varchar(25)"))
```

Why is the load failing to parse the single quotes correctly? What is a workaround that *does not involve removing the single quotes from the original file*?